# iOS 7: Importing CSV data from email attachement

Tags: ios, csv, cordova, email-attachments

I have a logging app that currently outputs a CSV as an email attachment. However, it's become somewhat critical to also allow users to import said CSV into other devices for sharing their logs.

It was somewhat trivial to get XCode to register CSV as one of the formats my app reads.  And I can even launch the app from Mail's "open with...".  However, I am having the hardest time working in Objective C (very different from what I am used to... PHP, JS, AS).

What I need help with is finding a working example as to how I can pass the CSV that was passed on from Mail into my app.

In Android, you can just declare "intent" and there are even Cordova Plugins, like WebIntent.  But nothing for iOS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you post questions when you not are interested in the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
//In the app delegate
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) 
  {
     [self.myViewController handleCSV:url];
  }
  return YES;
}


//In myViewController (or what you call it)

-(void)handleCSV:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSError *readError;
    NSString *csvString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:& readError];

    if(csvString && readError==nil)
    {
       NSArray *csvItems;
       NSRange matchComma= [csvString rangeOfString: @","];
       NSRange matchSemi= [csvString rangeOfString: @";"];

       if(matchComma.location != NSNotFound) csvItems = [csvString componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
       else if(matchSemi.location != NSNotFound) csvItems = [csvString componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
    }else
    {
      NSLog(@"error %@", readError);
    }
}
```